# How to install NVM?

Tags: nodejs, npm

I was having problem with permissions after installing Nodejs and npm. I tried removing them, I thought I was successful at first but then terminal showed me these messages.

I ran the command from github in my terminal.

What am I doing wrong / what should I do?

picture here:

[image]

Comment: We usually suggest you copy/paste error messages directly to the system, rather than using screenshots of error messages.  The error is "Failed to download" for those GitHub links.  Since it's likely you need those files, something is up with the downloader/script being used; you might need to do all the steps it's doing manually yourself

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, I solved it by cloning the repository directly (git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git) , then I cd into the folder and ran ./install.sh .

Comment: cause if you think of it that is exactly what the curl or wdget commands are doing .